# Google charts in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying to write the application on  MVC4.this application will display graphics and charts, based on the data from MSSQL. i tried to do this via  Google Chart, but it failed. point out at my mistake, please

```
@using System.Data;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Data.SqlClient;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Charts";
    string connectionString=@"Data Source=Juliya\SERVER;Initial Catalog=BASE;Integrated Security=True;";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        String rows = "";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Sotrud.Name, MS.MTime, ZAMER.P00 FROM  ZAMER INNER JOIN MS ON ZAMER.MSid = MS.MSid INNER JOIN Sotrud ON MS.Sotrudid = Sotrud.Sotrudid where MS.MTime>= '2011-01-02 10:14:00.000' and MS.MTime<= '2011-08-08 10:14:00.000' and Sotrud.Sotrudid=1005", conn))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                List<string> rowsList = new List<string>();

               // rowsList.Add("['Datum', 'Sava', 'RPWS1']");
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    //Converts your object into a DateTime (so that it's properties can be accessed properly
                    DateTime yourDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["MTime"]);


                    rowsList.Add("[new Date(" + yourDate.Year + ", " + (yourDate.Month - 1) + ", " + yourDate.Day + ", " + yourDate.Hour + ", " + yourDate.Minute + ", " + yourDate.Second + "), " + row["MTime"] + ", " + row["P00"] + "]");
                }
                rows = String.Join(", ", rowsList);
            };
        };
    }

    <title>Test Graph</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawChart() {
var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable()
data1.addColumn('datetime', 'MTime');
data1.addColumn('number', 'P00');
data1.addColumn('number', 'MTime');
data1.addRows([@Html.Raw(rows)]);

var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data1, {
height: 350,
width: 900,
title: 'Absolutna kota vode v tesnilni zavesi',
vAxis: {
maxValue: 165.5,
minValue: 159,
title: 'absolutna kota'
}
});
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
</script>
</head>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this](http://techblog.treenodes.com/index.php/2012/11/25/google-charts-with-mvc3/) blog post from a while it was about `creating google charts with MVC3` this will not differ a lot from MVC4

Comment: I read your post, but the problem is that I need to take the data for the graph database, people please help me